# Orientation of the sum of displaced 2d gaussians

Tags: fourier-analysis, image-processing, orientation

I'm interested in finding the orientation of the sum of 2d gaussians.

If one gaussian is placed at the origin, and another displaced along the x axis, the sum of the two is going to have an orientation along the x axis.

How can I show this analytically?

My initial thought was to take the Fourier Transform of the sum of the two gaussians, and analyse the magnitude of the transform to deduce the orientation - by taking the derivative and calculating the maxima, for instance.

I'm wondering whether there is some better method that I'm unaware of for such an analysis.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!